# Is it possible to make a contact form in html?

Tags: html, contact-form

I want to make a website which includes a questionnaire that visitors will fill in. Here is what I have:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<label>Name:</label>
<input name="name" placeholder="Name">

<label>Email:</label>
<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">

<label>Price:</label>
<select name="price" option="Free,1p - £1,£1 - £5,£5 - £10,£10 - £20,£20+"

<label>Comment:</label>
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Do you want to say anything else?"></textarea>

<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Most of it works, I can't get the drop down to work for some reason. Can you help please?

Comment: Can or Cannot is a individual thing. You are the only one who can answer the question. Or you may want to change the question title.

Comment: You're not closing the `<select>` tag, and it has no `<options>` in it. Also, HTML alone doesn't do much ... Have you implemented some server-side logic & location to store the info they submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<select>` element is wrong. You need to have child `<option>`s. See here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp

So, more like:

```
<select name="price">
    <option value="0">Free</option>
    <option value="0to1">1p - £1</option>
    <option value="1to5">£1 - £5</option>
    <!-- etc -->
</select>
```